# Why [^\We] instead of [^e] when looking for a word without e using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am studying Eloquent JavaScript chapter 9 and one of the problem is to find a word without e.

The answer contains a `[^\We]`, but I don't see why the `\W` is important there. Sure together the square bracket means anything in the set of word character and not letter e, but why can't I just omit the `\W`? I tried and it didn't work.

I had

```
/.*\b[^e]+\b.*/
```

which simply return everything. The correct answer is

```
/\b[^\We]+\b/i
```

.

Comment: There is also `[a-df-z]`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`\W` is a **non-word** character.  See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes).

Your regular expression is `[^\We]`.  This will match the negation of non-word characters and the letter 'e'.  In other words, it matches word characters except the letter 'e'.

You can't omit the `\W` because without it, your regexp will match everything except 'e', which isn't the requirement (match the set of word characters except 'e').